# Script works on Create, but in Edit doens't

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

guys.

I have a View on my ASP.NET MVC Project.
This View has a lot of fields and a script to search some data.

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/styles/people.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/people.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


<input type="hidden" id="selectiveAccess" name="selectiveAccess" value="@ViewBag.SelectiveAccess" />
<input type="hidden" id="peopleID" name="peopleID" value="@ViewBag.PeopleID" />

<div id="content">
<h1>People - Create</h1>
<h3>All the fields with (*) are required.</h3>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "People", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Partial("EnabledCourses")
    @Html.Partial("GeneralData")    
    @Html.Partial("AddressData")
    @Html.Partial("ContactData")    
    @Html.Partial("OtherInformations")
    @Html.Partial("Research")

    <a href="#top">Back to the top</a>
    <div id="divErrors"></div>

    <div id="actions">
        <ul style="list-style: none;">
            <li style="display: inline"><input type="reset" id="clear" style="height: 3em; width: 10em" value="Clear form" /></li>
            <li style="display: inline"><input type="submit" id="continue" style="height: 3em; width: 10em" value="Continue" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

When I call Index(), the script works fine.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.PeopleID = string.Empty;
    return View();
}
```

When I call Edit(), the same script doensn't works.

```
public ActionResult Edit(long peopleID)
{
    ViewBag.PeopleID = peopleID;
    return View("Index");
}
```

This is the script:

```
function searchCityByPostalCode() {

var postalCode = {
    'postalCode': $('#postalCode').val()
};

$.get(
    'people/SearchCityByPostalCode',
    postalCode,
    function (city) {
        // do something that works.
    }
);
}
```

Anyone knows the problem?
Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't see how the searchCityByPostalCode() script relates to the view you posted.  Where is it called from?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Bobson. Well, I'm using on blur event of a input called postalCode. $('#postalCode').blur(function() { // call my ajax function. });

Comment: Yeah. The script works when I call the Index page thru Index method. When I call trhu Edit method, this ajax callings doesn't works.

Comment: Is the blur being called at all?  Can you alert out from it to test?

Comment: When I call trhu Index, the alert into success ajax function appears with some message. When I call trhu Edit, appears alert only outside the ajax block. It's weird, really weird. :s

Comment: Do you know how to debug Ajax requests?  For example, can you see if the request is actually accepted by the server?  If you breakpoint inside the SearchCityByPostalCode function in PeopleController, does it hit when you are going through the edit path?

Comment: I've tried all these things. In Index path, the breakpoint is hited. In Edit path, it doesn't. I'm freaking out about it!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is is due to the relative link you are using.

Index allows you to do something like this

- www.mysite.com/Mycontroller/ - Goes to Index
- www.mysite.com/Mycontroller/Index - Goes to Index (same as above)

However edit would force you to use the second form since there is no default route value

- www.mysite.com/Mycontroller/Edit/{id}

Meaning that when you call the function for get in the index the request looks like

- www.mysite.com/Mycontroller/people/SearchCityByPostalCode

And edit looks like this which is a diffrent path

- www.mysite.com/Mycontroller/Edit/people/SearchCityByPostalCode

So basically you need to use an absolute reference so that the URL will work from the root of the site.

```
$.get(
    '/people/SearchCityByPostalCode',
    postalCode,
    function (city) {
        // do something that works.
    }
);
```

Comment: I'll bet this is it.  I've had exactly this problem before.  I should have recognized it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Bryan. I know all these things. The problem is not in the script, but is the script doesn't called when I call Edit page.

Comment: The URL on create is: http://localhost:63558/People. The URl on edit is: http://localhost:63558/Edit//{peopleID}, cause I've created a route for the Controller method.

Comment: Where is the script defined?  
(ie: $.get('people/SearchCityByPostalCode',.....)
Where are you initiating the call to the script? are you getting any output in the debug console in your browser?